# Looking for JShell input workaround

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I'm trying out the new JShell program with the [java9 jdk](https://jdk9.java.net/download/). I want to debug an interactive console app I'm making, but it seems `System.in` doesn't work. For example:

```
[root@mycomputer home]# jdk-9/bin/jshell 
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9-ea
|  Type /help for help

-> new Scanner(System.in).next()
```

It just freezes here and locks the keyboard up completely. I have to kill the process in another terminal in order to get my prompt back.

As [mlk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157672/mlk) points out, it looks like this is a [known bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131023). Has anyone found a workaround?

---

```
My specs: Redhat x86_64, Gnome-Terminal, Java9 Build 109
```

Comment: I think this is a [known bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131023).

Comment: @mlk that's really disappointing. I don't see any workarounds either. Was looking forward to trying it out, but I guess I'll have to wait until this bug gets resolved.

Comment: Is this limited to JDK 9?

Answer (score 1):

The only workaround I found is assigning the "input" to a string, and use `Scanner`'s [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-) that accepts a String:

> `public Scanner(String source)`
>
> Constructs a new `Scanner` that produces
>   values scanned from the specified string.

---

```
-> String input = "Hello world"
|  Added variable input of type String with initial value "Hello world"

-> Scanner sc = new Scanner(input)
|  Modified variable sc of type Scanner with initial value java.util.Scanner[delimiters=\p{javaWhitespace}+][position=0][match valid=false][need input=false][source closed=false][skipped=false][group separator=\,][decimal separator=\.][positive prefix=][negative prefix=\Q-\E][positive suffix=][negative suffix=][NaN string=\QNaN\E][infinity string=\Q∞\E]

-> sc.next()
|  Expression value is: "Hello"
|    assigned to temporary variable $5 of type String
```

Comment: this solution doesn't really work for me. I'd have to rip out a lot of code. I've been playing around with redirecting system.in to a custom input stream and creating the scanner on a different thread

Comment: @flkes JShell is not meant to be used for writing complicated code parts. It should be used to test little things, not implementing multithreaded projects. For that, I would still create a test project using an IDE.

Comment: I'm not writing the code in jshell, just debugging it. I should be able to use jshell and test my api.

Comment: @flkes I hope it'll be fixed in the next release.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug and it has been fixed (prior to the release of JDK 9).

```
jshell> new Scanner(System.in).next()
r
$1 ==> "r"
```